# How do I delete an image when I delete the post or the structure that contained it, with multer?

Tags: reactjs, express, multer

Maybe the question is not very clear so I will explain better. I made an app where I can create posts that have a title, some content and an image. The image is uploaded with multer in the root folder in a directory called `uploads`. As I create posts, the images uploaded with those posts are getting saved to this folder. The problem is that when I delete a post, the image doesn't get deleted along with everything else in the post, but they remain in the `uploads` directory. In time this can become problematic, as the number of images is ever increasing during the life of the app.

My question is how can i delete the images that pertain to the deleted posts, and how can I do it with multer, but any other solution would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need multer to delete the file. Since it's already on your disk you can use nodejs default library. Here's a sample.

```
const fs = require('fs')

const path = './file.txt'

fs.unlink(path, (err) => {
  if (err) {
    console.error(err)
    return
  }

  //file removed
})
```